# Aggregate SOQL not covering in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Here is the class.

```java
public class BillingHistoryList {
    public BillingHistoryList(){
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<string, Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper>> bHistoryOrders(Id recordId){
    Map<string, Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper>> resmap = new Map<string, Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper>>();
    if(recordId != null){
        String sobjectType = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        if(sobjectType =='Account'){
            List<Account> acc = [SELECT SF_Account_Number__c FROM Account WHERE id=:recordId Limit 1];            
            List<AggregateResult> aggriRes = [ SELECT SUM(Qty_Invoiced__c)QtyInvoiced, 
                                              SUM(Total_Contribution_USD__c)TotalContributionUSD, 
                                              SUM(Total_Value_USD__c)TotalValueUSD, 
                                              CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)InvoiceDate, 
                                              Product__r.Product_Center__c 
                                              From Billings__c 
                                              Where
                                              Invoice_Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:4 
                                              AND ( Account__r.SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR Project_Owner_SF_Acc_No__c =:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c)
                                              AND (Order_Status__c = 'Open' OR Order_Status__c = 'Closed') 
                                              GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c), Product__r.Product_Center__c ];
                                                // Account__c=:recordId OR SF_Account_Number__c  OR Project_Owner_Account__c =:recordId

            If( aggriRes.size() > 0 ) {
                    set<string> pCenterSet = new set<string>();
                    set<integer> iDate = new set<integer>();
                    for(AggregateResult res: aggriRes ){
                        String productCenter =(String) res.get('Product_Center__c');
                        pCenterSet.add(productCenter);
                            if (!resmap.containsKey(productCenter)){
                                resmap.put(productCenter, New Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper>());
                            }
                        Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper> currentProdMap = resmap.get(productCenter);
                            Integer invoiceDate =(Integer) res.get('InvoiceDate');
                            iDate.add(invoiceDate);                               
                            currentProdMap.put(invoiceDate, New BillingHistoryWrapper((Double)res.get('QtyInvoiced'),(Double)res.get('TotalContributionUSD'), (Double)res.get('TotalValueUSD')));
                                
                        resmap.put(productCenter,currentProdMap);   
                    }
                    for(string c : pCenterSet){
                        for(integer i : iDate){
                            if(!resmap.get(c).containsKey(i)){
                                Map<Integer,BillingHistoryWrapper> currentProdMap = resmap.get(c);
                                currentProdMap.put(i,New BillingHistoryWrapper(0,0,0));
                                resmap.put(c,currentProdMap);                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
        return resmap;
    }

    public class BillingHistoryWrapper {
        public  BillingHistoryWrapper(Double QtyInvo, Double TotCon, Double TotValUSD) {
            this.QtyInvoiced = QtyInvo;
            this.TotalContributionUSDList = TotCon;
            this.TotalValueUSDList = TotValUSD;
        }

        @AuraEnabled
        public  Double QtyInvoiced {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public  Double TotalContributionUSDList {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public  Double TotalValueUSDList {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public  Double totalValues {get; set;}
    }

    public class ProductCenter {
        @AuraEnabled
        public string productCenter {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public list<Years> Years    {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public Double totalByProductCenter  {get; set;}
    }

    public class Years {
        @AuraEnabled
        public string Year  {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public BillingHistoryWrapper billing{get; set;}
    }
}
```

And here is the test class which is unable to get cross aggriRes.size() > 0.

```java
@IsTest
public class BillingHistoryListTest {
    @isTest
    static void TestbHistoryOrders(){
        AccountTestDataFactory account = new AccountTestDataFactory();
        BillingsTestDataFactory billings = new BillingsTestDataFactory();
       
        SObject accountRecord = account.createRecord();
        SObject billingsRecord = billings.createRecord();
        
       
        test.startTest();
        List<Account> acc = [SELECT SF_Account_Number__c FROM Account WHERE id=:accountRecord.id];
        List<AggregateResult> aggriRes = [ SELECT SUM(Qty_Invoiced__c)QtyInvoiced,
                                              SUM(Total_Contribution_USD__c)TotalContributionUSD,
                                              SUM(Total_Value_USD__c)TotalValueUSD,
                                              CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)InvoiceDate,
                                              Product__r.Product_Center__c
                                              From Billings__c
                                              Where
                                              Invoice_Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:4 
                                              AND ( Account__r.SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR Project_Owner_SF_Acc_No__c =:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c)
                                              AND (Order_Status__c = 'Open' OR Order_Status__c = 'Closed') 
                                              GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c), Product__r.Product_Center__c ];
                
        BillingHistoryList.bHistoryOrders(accountRecord.id);       
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is not beeing covered?

Comment: tl;dr: You probably need to put more effort into your test setup.  Long version: You are responsible for ensuring that your test data is set up in such a way that the code that you want to test will be executed. I'm skeptical that your `createRecord()` methods (with no parameters being passed) are going to be sufficient here; not just for setting the `Invoice_Date__c` and the like appropriately, but also for setting up the relationship between your two test accounts. Also, you should be making assertions in your tests.

Comment: @EliveltonWalter  where the query ends. And in aggriRes i'm getting nothing(empty list). I think that could be a reason. Is there anything specific(special considerations) for creating aggregate soql test data ?

Comment: Aggregate data is not more than a bunch of records aggregated, in other words, you need to create at least one Billings__c which respects these followings filters: Invoice_Date__c >= LAST_N_YEARS:4 AND (Account__r.SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR SF_Account_Number__c=:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c OR Project_Owner_SF_Acc_No__c =:acc[0].SF_Account_Number__c) AND (Order_Status__c = 'Open' OR Order_Status__c = 'Closed') GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Invoice_Date__c), Product__r.Product_Center__c

Because on the test environment you do not have access to the actual data from the org